# Sharepoint search query fields missing in my 2010 sharepoint version

Tags: sharepoint, search, contenttype

The below query i used to search the content of the MOSS 2007 site and SP 2010 site.
I get the ContentType value in MOSS site.But if i use the same query with ContentType, It will give the malformed error.

SELECT Title, Rank, Size, Description, Write, Path, contentclass,FROM Scope()
WHERE FREETEXT(DefaultProperties, '1') ORDER BY "Rank" DESC

What the exactly the problem?. IS I need to add the ContentType column name in search service application(metadata propertie). or it need to do any configuration.

Also i am using sharepoint search tool there itself for 2010 it's not showing the ContentType Column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using following query

`SELECT Title, Rank, Size, Description, Write, Path, contentclass,FROM portal..scope()`  `WHERE FREETEXT(DefaultProperties, '1') ORDER BY "Rank" DESC`

I had faced same issue while I consumed Search.asmx and searching for MOSS 2007 site and SP2010. I was getting proper data for **MOSS 2007** using only **scope()** but for **SP 2010** I need to put **portal..scope()**.

Also have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073206/sharepoint-2010-freetextsqlquery-your-query-is-malformed-please-rephrase-your-q)

Comment: Thanks, With the portal.. its working fine. But the column name "ContentType" is the problem, I am not able to use the column name in my query. I need the column to filter the search result by content type of search result. As i told the "CotentType" column works fine with MOSS

Comment: I found this : The ContentType property is NOT marked retrievable in SharePoint 2010 and I have found no way to change this, so you cannot return it in your search results. (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/d11edbcb-32ca-4621-9c75-cad0c482d41e)

Comment: Thanks,  Then how do i find the content type of the rearch result. any idea other then this column name