# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E01

Tags: c#, sql, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-search

I'm trying to query the sharepoint search with the following code

```
    protected ResultTable Search(String query, SPWeb currentWeb)
    {
        ResultTable rt = null;

        try
        {
            FullTextSqlQuery q = GetFullTextSqlQuery(currentWeb);

            q.QueryText = query;

            q.RowLimit = int.MaxValue;
            rt = ((ResultTableCollection)q.Execute())[ResultType.RelevantResults];
            //q.Dispose();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rt = null;
            Logging.LogException(ex);
        }

        return rt;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create base FullTextSqlQuery
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>FullTextSqlQuery</returns>
    protected static FullTextSqlQuery GetFullTextSqlQuery(SPWeb currentWeb)
    {
        FullTextSqlQuery q = new FullTextSqlQuery(currentWeb.Site);

        q.Culture = new CultureInfo(1033);

        q.EnableStemming = false;
        q.TrimDuplicates = true;

        if (SPSecurity.AuthenticationMode != System.Web.Configuration.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
        {
            q.AuthenticationType = QueryAuthenticationType.PluggableAuthenticatedQuery;
        }
        else
        {
            q.AuthenticationType = QueryAuthenticationType.NtAuthenticatedQuery;
        }

        q.RowLimit = 200;

        q.StartRow = 0;
        q.IgnoreAllNoiseQuery = false;
        q.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;

        return q;

    }
```

And no matter what i do i get this exception: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E01

23-07-2012 14:53:45 Documenten  Search  System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]   Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E01

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ISearchQueryServiceApplication.Execute(QueryProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(ISearchServiceApplication serviceApplication)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoSpLoadBalancedUriWsOp[T](WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, String operationName)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoWebServiceBackedOperation[T](String operationName, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.Execute()
   at Rapportages.RapportageDocumenten.RapportageDocumenten.Search(String query, SPWeb currentWeb)

I read suggestions i should reduce the rowlimit, but i get this exception even with a rowlimit as low as 20.

Comment: According to this, remove the setting of `RowLimit`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073206/sharepoint-2010-freetextsqlquery-your-query-is-malformed-please-rephrase-your

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not change anything. still Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the fulltextsqlquery  in a using fixed the issue. Don't ask me why.

```
                   using (FullTextSqlQuery q = GetFullTextSqlQuery(web))
                    {
                        q.QueryText = sqlQuery.ToString();
                        rt = ((ResultTableCollection)q.Execute())[ResultType.RelevantResults];
                        Logging.LogMessage(rt.RowCount.ToString());
                    }
```